thermostat went blank , should i be worried
So its just the beginning of the cold weather, so we dont open the heat all day
today night, we set the thermostat to 21.5 Celsius, it start heating and then went blank
I notice that while blank the furnace was still on
Anyway, i pressed the thermostat button, nothing happened
I went to the breaker, turned it off, and then back on
now the thermostat seem fine
So the question, should i worry, is it a big risk
do i need to change the thermostat?
or can i wait, until, if it does this again?
The thermostat is aube, not sure what the model is, but its one that dont need or use batteries, and the furnace a baseboard heater
Thanks
Ali

is it Aube Line Voltage Thermostat 240S

not sure of the model, but could be that one or a similar model, its for a 240 baseboard heater
@diy75 it is most likely this model   #TH209

I can not predict the future, but be prepared to know where you can get a replacement in a hurry
